# I have PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/.cache'? on android kivy application

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

When I run my kivy app on android I get the error: " PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/.cache'"
Python version: 3.6.9
Kivy: (2.0.0)
Kivy-Garden: (0.1.5)
buildozer: (1.5.1.dev0)
Cython: (0.29.34)
OS: XUbuntu 18.04

Buildozer.spec file:

```
requirements = python3,kivy,fake_user_agent,beautifulsoup4,pyrogram,tgcrypto,pyQiwiP2P,requests,urllib3,chardet,certifi,idna,lxml,aiohttp,multidict,attr,yarl,async_timeout,attrs,Pillow,cchardet,charset-normalizer==2.1.1,aiosignal,frozenlist,android,libtool,pathlib2,pathlib

android.permissions = INTERNET,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
```

Logcat android:

```
`04-23 14:41:12.798  3353  3392 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):`
`04-23 14:41:12.799  3353  3392 I python  :    File "/home/bodya/program_nastena/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_22/python3/Lib/pathlib.py", line 1323, in mkdir`
`04-23 14:41:12.799  3353  3392 I python  :  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/.cache/fakeua'`
`04-23 14:41:12.799  3353  3392 I python  :`  
`04-23 14:41:12.799  3353  3392 I python  :  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`
`04-23 14:41:12.799  3353  3392 I python  :`  
`04-23 14:41:12.799  3353  3392 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):`
`04-23 14:41:12.799  3353  3392 I python  :    File "/home/bodya/program_nastena/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 8, in <module>`
`04-23 14:41:12.800  3353  3392 I python  :    File "/home/bodya/program_nastena/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/armeabi-v7a/fake_user_agent/`__`init`__`.py", line 3, in <module>`
`04-23 14:41:12.800  3353  3392 I python  :    File "/home/bodya/program_nastena/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/armeabi-v7a/fake_user_agent/user_agent.py", line 30, in <module>`
`04-23 14:41:12.800  3353  3392 I python  :    File "/home/bodya/program_nastena/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/armeabi-v7a/fake_user_agent/settings.py", line 12, in <module>`
`04-23 14:41:12.800  3353  3392 I python  :    File "/home/bodya/program_nastena/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_22/python3/Lib/pathlib.py", line 1327, in mkdir`
`04-23 14:41:12.801  3353  3392 I python  :    File "/home/bodya/program_nastena/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_22/python3/Lib/pathlib.py", line 1323, in mkdir`
`04-23 14:41:12.801  3353  3392 I python  :  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/.cache'`
`04-23 14:41:12.801  3353  3392 I python  : Python for android ended.`
```

Comment: You should not use hard coded paths. On Android there is no `home` directory. And inside `/data` folder you also have no write permissions.

Comment: @Robert I don't use this path anywhere in my code, one of the python libraries does it, if I'm not mistaken it's fake_user_agent.

Comment: Then I would check out the source code of that package, modify it locally and then install it into your venv used for developing the app.

Comment: @Robert I stopped using the fake_user_agent library and the application started as I expected, the problem was in the library itself. But after a while the application crashes with this error: " D DropBoxManagerService: #07 pc 00040151 /data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/jnius/jnius.so
04-28 23:11:28.304 868 19727 D DropBoxManagerService: #07 pc 00040151 /data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/jnius/jnius.so
"I installed the pyjnius library in xubunu and added it to the spec file, but the problem does not go away. Please help.

Comment: You should check which CPU architecture that .so file supports. I am not sure if it is the correct architecture for an Android device which usually uses arm-v7 or arm-v8 code.

Comment: @Robert how can I check this?

Comment: You can use tools like `readelf -h` in the `Machine` line the CPU architecture is displayed.

Comment: @Robert In logcat android the path to the .so file is relative to the application, but I don't quite understand where it is relative to the .buildozer folder in linux